# I am trying to create a cal_average function however I keep getting the syntax error that python cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, tuples

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMnZn.png)

I am trying to create a cal_average function, please see block of code below:

```
def cal_average(numbers):
       sum(list_name) = sum(numbers)
       len(list_name) = len(numbers)
       ave(list_name) = sum(list_name)/len(list_names)
       return ave(list_name)
```

`enter code here`    result = cal_average([3,4,5])

Comment: `sum(list_name)` is a call to the function `sum` on a variable called `list_name`. What you actually need in that position is a variable name e.g. `sum_numbers = sum(numbers)`. The same applies to the next two lines.

Comment: Do not post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear, you cannot assign to function call, in python `sum` is a build-in function also `len` is a built-in function, you can use `statistics.mean`:

```
import statistics

statistics.mean([3, 4, 5])
```

**output:**

```
4
```

or, if you want to keep your function:

```
def cal_average(numbers):
       return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```